# ARCGIS Javascript Need to select all feature in map

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis

I am using ArcGIS Javascript language, and using esri.tasks.FindTask, i wanna select all the features.

When i am passing the blank parameter than it is not working.
I am pasting some code. In this code i have searchid and seachField than execute method will call.

```
 var searchText = document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        findTask = new esri.tasks.FindTask(SearchURL);
        findParams = new esri.tasks.FindParameters();
        findParams.returnGeometry = true;
        findParams.layerIds = [searchId];
        findParams.searchFields = [seachField];                             
        findParams.searchText = searchText;
        findTask.execute(findParams, showResults);
```

but if suppose i will pass blank value in searchtext that time and it is not giving me any feature.

Any idea ...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that with custom behavior of the find task, you'll need to do a "workaround".

To get more flexibility with query you'll need to use query taks, and to get all files you can use this query bellow:

```
var query = new esri.tasks.Query("http://myarcgisserver:6080/arcgis/rest/services/mymapservice/MapServer/8");
query.where = "1=1";
query.outSpatialReference = {wkid:102100}; 
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = ["*"];
queryTask.execute(query, addPointsToMap);
```

As you ask, do a query in different layers need's one request for each layer, so if you want to do it through a findTask, you can use the `contains` parameters setted to `true` and guarantee that all fields have a blank space character, then to find all features you send a find with " " blank character.

Comment: But the problem in esri.tasks.Query() is we can search the feature in only one layer.
like...
 var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
            queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask(LayerName);
            query.where = WhereCondition;
            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.outFields = ["*"];
            queryTask.execute(query, showResultsForAdvance);

Comment: but Claudio i want to search all the feature of the map.. Is it possible with esri.tasks.Query()..

Comment: Ok thanks Claudio for reply i will try some other things. it seems it is not possible with single query..

Comment: you have a workaround, but is not the right solution, you can use the contains flag to true and guarantee that all fields have a space blank character, then when you want to find all features you send a find with " " blank character.